# Error sld generated for mbstyle in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I have activated the `mbstyle` plugin for GeoServer. This is part of a mbstyle, it contains a filter:

```
"filter": ["all", [">=", "scalerank", ["zoom"]]],
```

Which means I want to render only those features whose `scalerank` is `>=` the current zoom level.

And I found a sld file named the same as the mbstyle in the `$geoserver_data_dir/styles/xxx.sld`, this should be generated by geoserver, and the above filer is transformed as this:

```
  <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>scalerank</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>zoomLevel([env([wms_scale_denominator])], [EPSG:3857])</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

When I preview the layer, I got the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "zoomLevel([env([wms_scale_denominator])], [EPSG:3857])"

How can I fix this?

---

**Update for answer by @Andrea Aime:**

I found the `class ZoomLevelFunction extends FunctionExpressionImpl` which provide the `zoomLevel` function, so the transformation in the sld is right/expected. But Geoserver pass this expression to database for features querying directly instead of  evaluating it using the function. So is it the problem of geoserver or mbstyle?

Also follow [this PR](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/2930) mentioned by @Andrea Aime, I change my filter to :

```
"filter": ["all", [">=", ["get","scalerank"], ["zoom"]]],
```

And the sld changed to:

```
  <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>property([scalerank])</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>zoomLevel([env([wms_scale_denominator])], [EPSG:3857])</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

But I got error:

> This style specifies an attribute name property([scalerank]),not found in the xxx layer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MBStyle module for the moment supports only the old expression syntax, but not the current one. There is work ongoing to improve that:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/2930

Comment: Is it expected  to transform `zoom` to `zoomLevel([env([wms_scale_denominator])]`?

Comment: It is, there is no such a thing as "zoom" in the OGC rendering machinery, only scale denominators. That function turns the current scale denominator into the closest zoom level in the web mercator gridset assumed by MBStyle.

Comment: Hi, can you check my update?

Comment: That's a PR, that is, work in progress not yet available to end users.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.